# Wierd KendoUI Autocomplete bug with JSON datasource

Tags: jquery, json, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a list of object that was converted to JSON that I want to load in my KendoUi autocomplete control.

This code doesn't work

```
@{

    var suburbs = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Suburbs));

    <script>

    $(function () {

        var data = '@suburbs';

        $("#sSuburb").kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: data,
                filter: "startswith",
                placeholder: "Select suburb...",
                dataTextField: "SuburbName",
                dataValueField: "ID",
                separator: ", "
            });
     });
    <script>
}
```

but how come this one works

```
 var data = [{ "ID": 1, "SuburbName": "NEWSTEAD", "PostCode": "4006", "State": "QLD", "CountryCode": 1 }, { "ID": 2, "SuburbName": "NEWSTEADS", "PostCode": "4006", "State": "QLD", "CountryCode": 1 }, { "ID": 4, "SuburbName": "NEWS", "PostCode": "4006", "State": "QLD", "CountryCode": 1 }, { "ID": 5, "SuburbName": "NEWSTEST", "PostCode": "4006", "State": "QLD", "CountryCode": 1 },];

  $("#sSuburb").kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: data,
                filter: "startswith",
                placeholder: "Select suburb...",
                dataTextField: "SuburbName",
                dataValueField: "ID",
                separator: ", "
            });
```

needless to say, the JSON result are the same in both examples. Is there something I missing here?

UPDATE:

I also tried JSON.Stringify but still no luck

```
    var data = JSON.stringify(@suburbs);
```

this is the actual json result when I use alert(data);

```
[{"ID":1,"SuburbName":"NEWSTEAD","PostCode":"4006","State":"QLD","CountryCode":1},{"ID":2,"SuburbName":"NEWSTEADS","PostCode":"4006","State":"QLD","CountryCode":1},{"ID":4,"SuburbName":"NEWS","PostCode":"4006","State":"QLD","CountryCode":1},{"ID":5,"SuburbName":"NEWSTEST","PostCode":"4006","State":"QLD","CountryCode":1},{"ID":6,"SuburbName":"NETWORK","PostCode":"9006","State":"QLD","CountryCode":1},{"ID":7,"SuburbName":"NEW JERS","PostCode":"9006","State":"QLD","CountryCode":1},{"ID":8,"SuburbName":"SYDNEY","PostCode":"2001","State":"NSW","CountryCode":1},{"ID":9,"SuburbName":"SYDNEYHAM","PostCode":"2001","State":"NSW","CountryCode":1},{"ID":10,"SuburbName":"SYD","PostCode":"2001","State":"NSW","CountryCode":1},{"ID":11,"SuburbName":"SYRACUSE","PostCode":"2001","State":"NSW","CountryCode":1},{"ID":12,"SuburbName":"SYDTEST","PostCode":"9001","State":"NSW","CountryCode":1},{"ID":13,"SuburbName":"SYDDD","PostCode":"9001","State":"NSW","CountryCode":1}]
```

oviously the same with the hardcoded one.

but when I view it in firebug, and WATCH the `data` variable
in the first example, seems like it was treated just like a normal string

`"[{"ID":1,"SuburbName":"NEWSTEAD","PostCode":"4006","State":"QLD","CountryCode":1},{"ID":2,"SuburbName":"NEWSTEADS","PostCode":"4006","State":"QLD","CountryCode":1}....`

while in the second example, firebug's watch shows

`[Object { ID=1, SuburbName="NEWSTEAD", PostCode="4006", more...}, Object { ID=2, SuburbName="NEWSTEADS".......`

*Notice the `Object` thing in the second one. 
*The second one works fine.

Comment: Can you show the content of `@suburbs`? - You can get it using Console.log(`@suburbs`) or alert(`@suburbs`). It'll help identifying the issue.

Comment: See my edit, I used alert(data)

Comment: if i use alert(@suburb) this is the result - [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: I checked it using firebug and watch the `data` and seems like in the first example, the `data` was treated like a normal string, while in the second, it was list of object

Comment: in firebug watch window, the first example's 'data' was -  "`[{"ID":1,"SuburbName":"NEWSTEAD","PostCode":"4006","State":"QLD","CountryCode":1}....`

Comment: while the second example its `[Object { ID=1, SuburbName="NEWSTEAD", PostCode="4006", more...}, Object { ID=2, SuburbName="NEWSTEADS".....`

Comment: the second one works ok

Comment: I am not sure why the issue is there. One suggestion: use `Html Helper`-i.e.-`@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().BindTo(Model.Suburbs)` - [Demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html)

Comment: No, for some reason, kendoui html helper is not an option (long story but I was using Orchard CMS and  kendo html helper is not possible because the UI is exposed in the CMS editor, if you get what I mean).

Comment: it's just wierd how come the first one wasnt treated as list of objects

Comment: Then use [Kendo datasource](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/datasource/overview) and read the data from server from it.

Comment: That would be my last option, I have the REST service layer in the project and I don't want hardcoded URL's exposed in the client..

Comment: You can write URL in `@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { parameter = "" })` way instead of hardcoding it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the following statement:

```
var data = '@suburbs';
```

The "data" variable is a string which isn't a valid setting for the `dataSource` option. You can try `var data = @suburbs;` because you really want a JavaScript array not a string.

Comment: ok, it does show syntax error in the IDE (maybe a bug) but when you run it, its working. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Kendo datasource](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/datasource/overview) and read the data from server from it.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {            
            url: serverMethodURL,  // the remote service url
            dataType: "jsonp",     // JSONP is required for cross-domain AJAX

            // additional parameters sent to the remote service
            data: {
                q: "html5"
            }
        }
    },
    // describe the result format
    schema: {
        // the data which the data source will be bound to is in the "results" field
        data: "results"
    }
});
```

Then bind it to autocomplete (as in demo)

```
$("#sSuburb").kendoAutoComplete({
      dataSource: dataSource,....
```